# Using a member variable declared in the constructor in another function in the same class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I instantiate this class in a different file by saying `RunConfigurationController controller = new RunConfigurationController()`.

In the constructor, I make a new RunConfigurationView and then set the onclick functionality. Then when I run the program, and execute the cancel button click, I get an error saying that I cannot access `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRunConfigurationModal' of undefined`.

How can I access the "this" variable which I created in the constructor from another method inside the same class.

```
'use babel';

import RunConfigurationView from './run-configuration-view'

export default class RunConfigurationController {

  constructor() {
    this.runConfigurationView = new RunConfigurationView();
    this.runConfigurationView.getUpdateButton().onclick = this.updateButtonClick;
    this.runConfigurationView.getCancelButton().onclick = this.cancelButtonClick;

  }

  updateButtonClick() {

  }

  cancelButtonClick() {
    this.runConfigurationView.getRunConfigurationModal().remove();
  }

  getRunConfigurationView() {
    return this.runConfigurationView;
  }

}
```

Comment: tl;dr: `.onclick = () => this.updateButtonClick()`

Comment: Thanks much @Ryan!

Answer (score 0):

It's your binding...adjust these two lines in your constructor

```
this.runConfigurationView.getUpdateButton().onclick = this.updateButtonClick.bind(this);
this.runConfigurationView.getCancelButton().onclick = this.cancelButtonClick.bind(this);
```

See [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56) or [here](http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html) for more info